# pip install pyscipopt on mac - scip.h file not found

Tags: python, macos, scip

**Initial Question**
I've installed scipopsuite by following these instructions: http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/MAKE.php#BRIEFINSTALL

Make tests - complete without error.

Then when I try `pip install pyscipopt` I get the following error.

```
src/pyscipopt/scip.c:467:10: fatal error: 'scip/scip.h' file not found
#include "scip/scip.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Specs: Anaconda Python 2.7, latest OSX

**Follow Up**
In response to comments(@mattmilten),  I've done the following.

(1) Installed the make file -  When i tried to run the install it failed because the name of the O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.shared.opt folder was set to 'static' instead of shared. I changed that name and then the install completed but did have these warnings:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: lib/libscipopt-4.0.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a(stkchk.o) has no symbols 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: lib/libscipopt-4.0.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a(stkchk.o) has no symbols
```

When i try:

```
>>> import pyscipopt
```

, I now get the following error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/"local"/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___gmp_version
Referenced from: /Users/"local"/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/"local"/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so
```

I'm guessing these things are linked - thanks.

Comment: There are issues with the installation on some Mac machines. In the next few days we're releasing a bugfix version of SCIP that comes with a new CMake build system, which should solve your problem. For now I can only recommend you to try a minimal SCIP installation, i.e. `make install GMP=false READLINE=false ZIMPL=false ZLIB=false`, to avoid library dependency issues,

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [PySCIPOpt INSTALL](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md#requirements) you need to tell Python where you installed the SCIP Opt Suite: `export SCIPOPTDIR=<path_to_install_dir>`
The `setup.py` looks for this environment variable so you need to set it before you run `pip install pyscipopt`

**Edit:**

You need to *install* the SCIP Opt Suite (this basically copies the compiled files to some directory) as also explained in the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md#requirements)

Comment: Ok - (1) so this leads to another question - and likely to my being unfamiliar with the `make` process. It looks like the all the files are still stored on the Desktop in the folder where I ran the `make` command. Do i need to set a destination for the install?   (2) I tried setting the path to the "scipoptsuite-4.0.0" folder on the desktop, but should it be the "scipoptsuite-4.0.0/scip-4.0.0" folder within? Thanks!